# doctrine2: reference the join-table in a many-to-many relation

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony and Doctrine
This might be a simple question but i cannot seem to find the answer to it...

How can i reference the join-table of a many-to-many association in a querybuilder ?

I have 2 entities: Article and Tag with a many-to-many bidirectional relation

this creates the extra join-table :

```
article <-> article_tag <-> tag
```

I can reference the article table by selecting it from the Article Entity :

```
$this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    ->select('a')
    ->from('Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Article','a')
```

And i can reference the tag table by selecting it from the Tag Entity :

```
$this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    ->select('t')
    ->from('Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Tag','t')
```

Now how can i select things from the join-table ? There is no entity for it...

Comment: to interact with the middle table (n-m) you only need to add the functions addTag/addArticle in article/tag entity, and your private $tags should be and array initialized in your class construct (check this link: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant interact with this table. Doctrine will handle it, and like Roger Guasch said on the comments, you have to create accessors to the corresponding entities.

If you need to interact directly with this entity, you must define it by yourself, threating the m-n table as an entity. Then you can make reference to it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thx ! and also thx to Roger Gausch :)

Good to know i can create an entity for it if i really need to interact with this table.